# Upload CSV data into SQL Database using MVC and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, csv

I am new MVC framework and trying to figure out on how to Parse the CSV file in such a way that only data from certain columns are saved to the database.

I am able to select the CSV file and upload it via the View and pass it to my controller using the following code as mentioned here [Codelocker](http://www.codelocker.net/30401/c-sharp-upload-a-file-in-dot-net-mvc-and-read-the-contents-of-the-file-ex-csv-file/)

```
public ActionResult UploadMultipleFiles(FileUploadViewModel fileModel)
{
    //open file
    if (Request.Files.Count == 1)
    {
        //get file
        var postedFile = Request.Files[0];
        if (postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //read data from input stream
            using (var csvReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(postedFile.InputStream))
            {
                string inputLine = "";

                //read each line
                while ((inputLine = csvReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //get lines values
                    string[] values = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ',' });

                    for (int x = 0; x < values.Length; x++)
                    {
                        //do something with each line and split value
                    }
                }

                csvReader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

However, I am not really sure as how to only select the required columns in CSV file and store it to the database?

Any suggestions guys?

Comment: You should already know the schema of your CSV file. By taking `values[x]` you can build your query or assign to your database variable based on particular columns `x`.

Comment: How many rows on average will be in those CSVs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by creating a `DataTable` method where by creating required columns and then using `StreamReader` and looping through the lines and selecting the required columns

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadMultipleFiles()
{
    FileUploadService service = new FileUploadService();

    var postedFile = Request.Files[0];

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(postedFile.InputStream);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    DataTable dt = CreateTable();
    DataRow dr;
    string s;
    int j = 0;

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //Ignore first row as it consists of headers
            if (j > 0)
            {
                string[] str = s.Split(',');

                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Postcode"] = str[0].ToString();
                dr["Latitude"] = str[2].ToString();
                dr["Longitude"] = str[3].ToString();
                dr["County"] = str[7].ToString();
                dr["District"] = str[8].ToString();
                dr["Ward"] = str[9].ToString();
                dr["CountryRegion"] = str[12].ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    service.SaveFilesDetails(dt);
    sr.Close();
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: Since you are accessing a file, you should think of converting synchronous requests to asynchronous requests by converting synchronous action methods to asynchronous action methods.

Comment: Not relevant to the answer but you can also look at this file helper library to handle the logic of processing the file. http://www.filehelpers.net/